# Is there a way to use tokens in a Views: Link Display setting?

Tags: 7, views, tokens

*This question pertains to Drupal 7 and Views 3 (specifically 7.23 and Views 7.x-3.7):*

**Is there a way to enable the use of custom tokens within Drupal Views Link Display settings?**

My use case is a View Block with a More Link, which needs to point to a dynamic URL.

I was hoping to enable the use of tokens derived from this View's Fields (such as path or id) within the Link Display setting, so as to generate a custom More Link url.

Thanks!